# Workaround for position:fixed in IE7 onwards

Tags: css, internet-explorer

According to [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531140(v=vs.85).aspx):

> Starting in Internet Explorer 7. Fixed positioning is only supported
>   for pages using a strict `<!DOCTYPE>` directive.

We absolutely need to use `position:fixed` in our project.
However, we do not have control of the document type since we are creating a widget for client websites. Also, we are not allowed by our boss to embed our widget in an `iframe`.

Are there any known workarounds to simulate `position:fixed` in IE7 onwards?

Comment: It's the year 2016. Why support IE7?

Comment: @Vucko in the UK for example there are a huge number of public sector and private businesses that are stuck on windows xp simply because it either would a cost too much to upgrade or they have bespoke software they use that will not work on any other operating system. Yes they could install a third party browser but some businesses just don't. If it ain't broke...don't fix it and it ain't broke to them.

Comment: That was for HTML4 i think. You dont need that for HTML5  as there's no difference between "strict" and "transitional".

Comment: @Tasos Does that statement hold for CSS as well?

Comment: @Vucko We are supporting IE10 and IE11 not IE7.

Comment: @IanChuTe from you OP I thought that you need IE7 support also. _"However, we do not have control of the document type since we are creating a widget for client websites"_ - so, what `doctype` does the clients website has?

Comment: @Vucko Our widget has to be flexible enough to work with, possibly, any DOCTYPE

Comment: well Yes. if you check the page it says CSS 2.1 and we are now @ 3. So the Page is very old and hasn't been updated

Comment: I wish someone would actually answer the question instead of bashing it.